# How to pause form submit, for 1 last validation, at the very end and after that release/trigger/continue the submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a page1.php and i have a fly.php. page1.php is a simple (regular) form page, where people put info, when user submit the form.

- via ajax it loads the captcha template and ask to verify on the fly (till here is fine).
- After onFly validation, i want to allow this .submit() continue

Question: `How can i after .submit() pause for validatio`n of this captcha and after validation successfull, resume the form submission (which is on hold)?

Example:

**Part 1: page1.php**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('.callmeback').submit(function()
 {
    $.ajax({
        type    : "GET",
        url     : "/include/class/fly.php",
        data    : "a=b",
        async   : false,
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $(document.body).find('.blackwindow').remove();
            $(document.body).find('.nospam').remove();  
        },  
        complete: function()
        {
        },      
        success : function(msg)
        {
           $(document.body).append(msg);
           $('.blackwindow').css({
              'opacity':'0.90'
           });

           $('.nospam').find('input[type="button"]').live("click", function()
           {
              // final validation
              var security= $('.nospam').find('#security').val();
              var random  = $('.nospam').find('#random').val();

                  if (random!=security)
              { 
            alert ('Invalid captcha.');
            return false;

               } else  {
            // Basically its second time? and return true?                      
               }

           });

        }

    });

    //return false;
 });

});

<form method=post action=thanks.php class="callmeback">
<input type=text value=100.00 name=amount />
<input type=submit value=submit name=submit />
</form>
```

**Part 2: fly.php**

```
<? require_once 'obj.php';?>
.blackwindow {
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index:1000;

        background-color:#000000;
}

.nospam {
        position:fixed;
        top:30%;
        left:30%;
        padding:12px;
        border:solid 3px #686868;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        z-index:1001;
}
<div class="blackwindow"></div>
<div class="nospam">
<div>
<?
$value = obj::getRandom();                                          
echo '<img src="include/class/return_img.php?number=' . $value . '" />';
echo "<input type='hidden' id='random' name='random' value='$value' />";
?>     
<div>
*Please enter the above code below, to verify this request <br/>
<input type="text" class="textbox" id="security" name="security" />
</div>
</div>
<div>
<input type=button name=mybutton value="Verify" />
</div>
</div>
```

**Follow up (proof read):**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('.callmeback').find('input[type="button"]').live("click", function()
 {
    $.ajax({
        type    : "GET",
        url     : "/include/class/fly.php",
        data    : "a=b",
        async   : false,
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $(document.body).find('.blackwindow').remove();
            $(document.body).find('.nospam').remove();  
        },  
        complete: function()
        {
        },      
        success : function(msg)
        {
           $(document.body).append(msg);
           $('.blackwindow').css({
              'opacity':'0.90'
           });

           $('.nospam').find('input[type="button"]').live("click", function()
           {
              // final validation
              var security= $('.nospam').find('#security').val();
              var random  = $('.nospam').find('#random').val();

                  if (random!=security)
              { 
            alert ('Invalid captcha.');
            return false;

               } else  {
            $('.callmeback').submit();                      
               }

           });

        }

    });

    //return false;
 });

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pause form submission for validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205574/pause-form-submission-for-validation)

Comment: No, the code is not the same.  But the desired outcome -- holding off on submitting a form until some other validation has occurred -- is exactly the same.  The only difference is the nature of the validation.

Comment: The idea, the principle (and the code to hold off on the submit) is the same -- the validation is the only major difference, and the code for that is useless to anyone who doesn't have your exact problem (ie: who isn't you).  If we follow your logic, then we can't close a question like "How can i pause form submission to show a new window with a confirmation page?", because the thing you're waiting for is different.  I'm not buying it.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I will remove such link from other threads. But this question was my problem/real problem, so i have to keep it for my own reference only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to make the "submit" button not actually a `<input type='submit'>` button, but rather just a standard `button`. If validation passes, you can manually submit the forum using `$('form').submit()` or something similar.

Comment: Yes, but in that case, i have to have  two forms a dummy one, and from dummy i have to paste in  to final form and release the final form.

Comment: @IamSon0fRaja - Why? Just have a single form. When the user presses `<input type='button' value='Submit'>`, it will call the captcha on the fly. Based on the results of the captcha validation you can just continue with your function. It's a simple addition of an `if` block to your jquery code; if passes validation, submit.

Comment: @eykanal: i dont think you can do this way you are mentioning. Its 1 way round, page1.php is real form, i require to ask user twice  to submit the final form. Or i may not getting what exactly you mean, Do you have any dummy example, how you are thinking..

Comment: Do you mean? <form> <input type=button value=falsesubmit />  <input type=submit value=mainsubmit /> </form>. When falsesubmit occures it ask  captcha, and after validation it trigger() "mainsubmit"?

Comment: Close.. you don't have to have the user press `submit` in order to submit the form, you can do it programmatically. Read the documentation on the [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function to understand what I'm talking about.